# Where to query the state in a React app with normalized store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, storybook

I'm working on an React app using Redux to manage multiple entity types in a Redux store. In order to configure the store I used the Redux Toolkit which offers a great approach to define all the slices for the entity types using `EntityAdapter`s.

Thinking of the Blog example I have a slice for Posts, Comments and Users, offering according (async) actions, reducers and selectors.

The backend provides an endpoint to fetch all the Posts, Comments and related Users for a given time period. To put the data from the response in the corresponding slices I defined an additional action in its own file, which I use in the files defining the slices to specify a corresponding reducer.

Great stuff, works fine.

Questions now arise while implementing a view which renders a Post and its Comments. Until now I tried  to make React Components which only render information as dumb (agnostic) as possible. Throughout prototyping I had all the Posts, Comments and Users in a not-normalized JSON-like structure. Thus I passed all information to render as props. This makes writing tests and [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/)s quite easy.

But as I now have all the information to render in my store, I started to retrieve data from the store in these simple React Components using `useSelector`:

*Old approach*

```js
export const Comment = ({username, date, title, comment}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{username}@{date}</p>
      <em>{title}</em>
      <p>{comment}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

// Posts were provided in a JSON structure in a not-normalized manner.
export const PostView = ({post}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
      {post.comments && post.comments.map((comment) => {
        return <Comment username="{comment.username}" date="{comment.date}" title="{comment.title}" comment="{comment.comment}" />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

*New approach*

```js
export const Comment = ({commentId}) => {
  const comment = useSelector((state) => selectComment(state, commentId));
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{comment.username}@{comment.date}</p>
      <em>{comment.title}</em>
      <p>{comment.comment}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

// Posts were provided in a JSON structure in a not-normalized manner.
export const PostView = ({postId}) => {
  const post = useSelector((state) => selectPost(state, postId));

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
      {post.comments && post.comments.map((commentId) => {
        return <Comment commentId="{comment.id}" />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

While the "new" approach allows to only update Components which need to be updated and also reduces the Component interface quite well, there is also a drawback: now it's necessary to mock a matching Redux store for tests as well as for the Storybook. And speaking of the Storybook: it's now impossible to let the Storybook user change the props of a Component.

Unfortunately, a "mixed" approach won't work:

*Mixed approach*:

```js
export const Comment = ({username, date, title, comment}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{username}@{date}</p>
      <em>{title}</em>
      <p>{comment}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export const PostView = ({postId}) => {
  const post = useSelector((state) => selectPost(state, postId));

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
      {post.comments && post.comments.map((commentId) => {
        const comment = useSelector((state) => selectComment(state, commentId));
        return <Comment username="{comment.username}" date="{comment.date}" title="{comment.title}" comment="{comment.comment}" />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Now I'm wondering if I really need to implement the "new approach" which would mean to put some extra work on tests and stories and to lose the feature to change props in the Storybook? Or is there an approach I missed on my search on how to attach my Components to the Store but keep a simple Component interface?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had the idea to wrap the `Comment` component like in the following. Seems to be an accepted approach as it is similar to the distinction between "smart" and "presentational" components in [a blog post about React anti patterns](https://isamatov.com/react-antipatterns/).

```js
export const Comment = ({username, date, title, comment}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{username}@{date}</p>
      <em>{title}</em>
      <p>{comment}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export const CommentWrapper = ({commendId}) => {
  const comment = useSelector((state) => selectComment(state, commentId));

  return <Comment username="{comment.username}" date="{comment.date}" title="{comment.title}" comment="{comment.comment}" />;
};

export const PostView = ({postId}) => {
  const post = useSelector((state) => selectPost(state, postId));

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
      {post.comments && post.comments.map((commentId) => {
        return <CommentWrapper commentId="{comment.id}" />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Of course, I now introduced a Component which needs its own tests.